# Sequence with two different norm limits

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I know that there are a lot of examples of a sequence that converges to two different limits with respect to two complete norms.

But can we build for ANY normed space X two norms and a sequence $x_n$ that

$$
\| x_n - 0 \|_1 \to 0 , \, \| x_n - x \|_2 \to 0, \, x \neq 0
$$

**Edit**: Sorry, i forgot to mention that $\dim X = \infty$.

Comment: So you want a vector space with two norms, and it must be complete with respect to both, is that right?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I think completeness is not essential